# You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create function which returns last inserted id, but its  showing error while function call:
Will you please help me to identify my error.

> ERROR:  function public.insert_voucher(integer, unknown, unknown, integer, integer, unknown) does not exist
>   LINE 1: select public.insert_voucher(1, 'P', '20180909', 1, 1, 'txt');

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_voucher(
     in_orgid smallint
    ,in_transtype character
    ,in_date character
    ,in_partnerid smallint
    ,in_quantity smallint
    ,in_remarks character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
insert into 
public.transaction_header(
   org_id
  ,trans_type
  ,fiscal_year
  ,date
  ,partner_id
  ,quantity
  ,remarks
  ,create_by
  ,create_ts)
values (
   in_orgid
  ,in_transtype
  ,1819
  ,in_date
  ,in_partnerid
  ,in_quantity
  ,in_remarks
  ,1
  ,now())
returning trans_header_id;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1;
```

Table Schema:

```
trans_header_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('transaction_header_trans_header_id_seq'::regclass)
,org_id smallint NOT NULL
,trans_type character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'P'::bpchar
,fiscal_year smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1819'::smallint
,date date NOT NULL
,partner_id smallint NOT NULL
,quantity smallint NOT NULL
,remarks character varying(100)
,create_by smallint NOT NULL
,create_ts timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
,update_by smallint
,update_ts timestamp without time zone
,CONSTRAINT transaction_header_pk PRIMARY KEY (trans_header_id)
,CONSTRAINT create_by FOREIGN KEY (create_by)
REFERENCES public.app_user (user_id) MATCH FULL
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
,CONSTRAINT org_id FOREIGN KEY (org_id)
          REFERENCES public.organization (org_id) MATCH FULL
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
,CONSTRAINT partner_id FOREIGN KEY (partner_id)
          REFERENCES public.partners (partner_id) MATCH FULL
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
,CONSTRAINT update_by FOREIGN KEY (update_by)
          REFERENCES public.app_user (user_id) MATCH FULL
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
,CONSTRAINT org_fy_transtype_transno UNIQUE (org_id, trans_type, fiscal_year)
```

With reference @muistooshort and @stickybit, I am updating previous function.
Hope it will give more clarity and returns desired result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_voucher(
    IN in_orgid smallint
    ,IN in_transtype character
    ,IN in_date date
    ,IN in_partnerid smallint
    ,IN in_quantity smallint
    ,IN in_remarks character varying
    ,OUT out_id smallint)
  RETURNS smallint AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
    insert into 
    public.transaction_header(
       org_id
      ,trans_type
      ,fiscal_year
      ,date
      ,partner_id
      ,quantity
      ,remarks
      ,create_by
      ,create_ts)
    values (
       in_orgid
      ,in_transtype
      ,1819
      ,in_date
      ,in_partnerid
      ,in_quantity
      ,in_remarks
      ,1
      ,now())
    RETURNING trans_header_id
    INTO out_id;
    END
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1;
```

Comment: @muistooshort This is date format (YYYYMMDD) casted into character.

Comment: `INSERT INTO transaction_header(org_id,trans_type,fiscal_year,date,partner_id,quantity,remarks,create_by,create_ts)
values(1,'P','1819','20180909',1,1,'txt',1,now())` statement will work for same table schema.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, I agree to change input as `date` instead of `character`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `smallint`s are the problem. A cast from `integer` to `smallint` can mean losing some information. The engine won't do implicit casts, where information can get lost. Therefore it considers `public.insert_voucher(integer, unknown, unknown, integer, integer, unknown)` as not an option.

If you explicitly cast the numbers to `smallint`, the call should work.

```
SELECT public.insert_voucher(1::smallint, 'P', '20180909', 1::smallint, 1::smallint, 'txt');
```

There are some other things like why you pass a date as a string and `'1819'::smallint` (why the string first?). And some other problem may arise once the call works. But that's beyond the current question.

Comment: @muistooshort: I'm not entirely sure on this, but I have some faint memories, that Postgres ignores the length parameters for string values in function signatures. And passes it around as `text` anyway. So I believe this may probably not be a problem. But as I said, I'm not sure on this.

Comment: @muistooshort: Yes I agree. A date should be a `date`.

Comment: Thank you @stickybit. Can you please explain that difference between `Insert Command` and `Function command`, why it required type cast for `Function command`?